# Is this possible to get azure token using only userId and password?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I don't want to use client Id & Client Secret of azure AD App to generate token, 
If there is any way to generate azure token with help of only user id and password ?
[Token using client Id & secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q71j.png)

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To get azure token(access token or id token), you **must** provide client Id. If the application is native, the client secret is not needed.

[image]

Then you can get the token without secret.

[image]

**Update:**

Since you enabled multi-factor authentication, you can not use ROPC flow. The users will be blocked.

> How to access azure management api?

1.send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &scope=https://management.azure.com/.default &state=12345`

2.get access token with scope `https://management.azure.com/.default`

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Update2:**

Check if you have added the Azure Service Management api to the permissions list.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204517/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-ju-is-this-possible-to-get-azure-token-using-only-u).